# Option Menu dosn't show in fragment using collapsingToolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, optionmenu

For some reason my Fragment never calls `onCreateOptionsMenu` to inflate my menu, the overflow menu never appears and pressing the menu button in the emulator also does nothing.

And I tried to put `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` once in `onCreateView` but nothing happened after this I tried to put `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in the same Function but nothing happened again?

Answer (score 1):

you have to Write both of the lines together to make it work in onCreateView Function inside your fragment.
The Lines:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(your_toolbar);
```